# How do I mark an application as a web application? (As opposed to a virtual directory.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, web-applications

I have a web application project that I published and it turns out it's not marked at the web hosts as a web application. I have other applications and they are all marked as web applications, and I can't find a difference between them and this one neither in `web.config` nor in the properties of the project. But I assume I *am* missing some difference because of the different result.

So, where in a Visual Studio Asp.net web application project do I mark the application as an actual web application?

(I searched for a solution, but most information on the internet seems to be directed at how to mark as a virtual directory, what's the difference between them at all, etc.)

Comment: The difference between *web application* and *virtual directory* is in **IIS** not in VS.

Comment: please explain how do you install it on IIS?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev The difference might be in IIS but it's somehow automatically done every time I publish a new site without me setting anything in IIS, and yet was not done this time. That's what I'm after - how is it done automatically when published from Visual Studio.

Comment: @hassan.ef I just click on `Build` > `Publish` in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like publishing from Visual Studio is enough.

The problem with that specific application might have been a bug on the web hosting service of some sort.

So, again, the answer is: Visual Studio tells IIS to mark it as a web application. There is nothing (apparently) on the project's properties nor in web.config.